# Somar valores tabela

Tags: c#, .net

Possuo uma tabela onde retorno os valores pagos por contribuinte mensalmente.
Porém necessito criar um campo de subtotal, somando os valores de cada mês. Muito parecido com a Sequência de Fibonacci. O problema é que preciso buscar até quando o contribuinte realizou o pagamento. Nesta parte que estou me enrolando.

Os dados que eu tenho atualmente:

[image: Dados Atual]

Como necessito que os dados retornem:

[image: Dados Finais]

Tentei algo como:

```
 double a = 0;
        double AnoContribuinte = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            a = a + Contribuinte;
            i++;
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
```

Só que assim limitei a `i< 10`, e na verdade eu necessito que I seja igual a quantidade de dados que a tabela possui.

Porém desta forma ele entra em um *loop* infinito, pois `I` sempre terá algum valor.

Comment: você quer que o banco retorne uma View com esta informação? ou este campo SubTotal existe apenas na Model da sua aplicação?

Comment: Pelo visto, i nunca será null e por isso seu for nunca terminará. Outra coisa, se for adicionando o subtotal dessa forma, ele no final do for terá o último valor atribuído. O ideal é você pegar o count da primeira tabela e fazer o FOR por ele e para cada valor somado ao subtotal, você já vai descarregando no grid, pelo entendido, ou guardar em uma lista e depois pegar o grid e atribuir essa lista ao datasource do grid e bindar ele.

Comment: @TobyMosque este campo SubTotal existe apenas na Aplicação.

Comment: De onde vem esse `Contribuinte`? Ele não varia. Onde está sua tabela? Este trecho e as informações passadas não dão indicações de como resolver o problema.

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade, gostaria de te dá um conselho que foge um pouco a sua duvida. evite declarar variaveis como `a`, sempre tente utilizar algo que descreva melhor a variavel em si, como `subTotal`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vejo alguns problemas neste código:

1. O código parece estar manipulado valores monetários e usando o tipo [`double`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), isto não dá acerto, você terá problemas de arredondamento.
2. Está incrementando `i` duas vezes, não imagino porque isto é necessário.
3. Os dados sendo pegos não variam.

O que dá para ajudar é com isto:

```
var listaContribuintes = PegaContribuintes(); // este método traz os contribuintes de algum lugar
Decimal subTotal = 0;

foreach (var item in listaContribuintes) {
    subTotal += item.Contribuinte;
    item.SubTotal = subTotal;
}
```

Código:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        //as primeiras linhas abaixo é o mesmo que seria o método PegaContribuintes que eu usei no exemplo da resposta
        var pessoas = new List<Pessoa> { 
            new Pessoa { Nome = "Elias Vieira1", Contribuinte = 31.87m },
            new Pessoa { Nome = "Elias Vieira2", Contribuinte = 32.87m },
            new Pessoa { Nome = "Elias Vieira3", Contribuinte = 33.87m },
            new Pessoa { Nome = "Elias Vieira4", Contribuinte = 34.87m }
        };
        decimal subTotal = 0;
        foreach (var item in pessoas) {
            subTotal += item.Contribuinte;
            item.SubTotal = subTotal;
            WriteLine($"Nome: {item.Nome}, Contribuição: {item.Contribuinte}, SubTotal: {item.SubTotal}");
        }
    }
}

public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Contribuinte { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/O8Bomj). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SRvwB9). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/SubTotal.cs). Você tem que adaptar para a sua lista, seja como ela está composta.

Se tiver mais detalhes eu atualizo a resposta.

Comment: Desculpa por não postar os dados necessários, mas eu mesmo não sabia qual era realmente meu problema, ai postei uma versão simplificada.
Vou elaborar uma pergunta mais elabora, sobre meu real problema. Seu código me ajudou a observar qual o meu problema, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Então vamos supor o seguinte modelo:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public double Contribuinte { get; set; }
    public double SubTotal { get; set; }
}
```

E temos a seguinte lista, no exemplo abaixo está sendo carregada estaticamente:

```
var pessoas = new List<Pessoa>();
pessoas.Add(new Pessoa { Nome = "Elias Vieira", Contribuinte = 31.87d });
pessoas.Add(new Pessoa { Nome = "Elias Vieira", Contribuinte = 31.87d });
pessoas.Add(new Pessoa { Nome = "Elias Vieira", Contribuinte = 31.87d });
pessoas.Add(new Pessoa { Nome = "Elias Vieira", Contribuinte = 31.87d });
```

Você pode percorrer da seguinte forma:

```
var subTotal = 0.0d;
foreach(var pessoa in pessoas)
{
    subTotal += pessoa.Contribuinte;
    pessoa.SubTotal = subTotal;
}
```

Comment: Desculpa por não postar os dados necessários, mas eu mesmo não sabia qual era realmente meu problema, ai postei uma versão simplificada.
Vou elaborar uma pergunta mais elabora, sobre meu real problema. Seu código me ajudou a observar qual o meu problema, muito obrigado.

Comment: Marquei a resposta do @Bigown como a certa, pois ela possui um exemplo que pode ajudar outras pessoas que possuírem uma dúvida semelhante.

Answer (score 0):

Como sugestão, eu deixaria o banco de dados resolver o problema, olha este artigo, muito bom, em inglês!

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3112381/SQL-Server-Calculating-Running-Totals-Subtotals-and-Grand-Total-Without-a-Cursor.htm

Espero que ajude!

Comment: o custo para realizar uma subquery no SELECT tende a ter um custo elevado, especialmente quando a consulta retorna muitos registros. Neste caso especifico o ideal é utilizar uma combinação de CTE, temporary tables ou até mesmo cursores.
leia mais em: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals

Comment: Muito bom o artigo Toby, reforça o ponto que esse tipo de calculo é melhor de ser feito no banco e não no código!

Comment: Eu só tenho acesso a View que retorna esses dados. E esse campo em específico já utiliza um SUM() de outra tabela. Ex: **select SUM(tabela.campo) as Contribuinte...** Não sei se posso resolver o problema no campo apelas com o Alias do campo, na criação de uma View.